# Handling LTPA token timeout (websphere 7.x) in JSF richfaces 3.3

Tags: timeout, websphere, richfaces, httpsession, ltpa

I am using JSF richfaces 3.3 on websphere server 7.x.

The problem is when 
user logged in to the application using a browser window and had kept it open for more than LTPA token time out time then LTPA token expiration exception is occurring. Then page is not redirecting to the "logout" page configured. But it getting redirected to the Login page and after successful login then a weird xml page is displayed.
I understand that this is happening because on LTPA token time out when we try to access a JSF resource, as no authentication details are present page is being redirected to login page.
Then as no proper session is present Faces context is still trying to access previous session JSF tree this exception is occurring.

So Question is: How to handle this scenario of LTPA token time out in JSF richfaces3.3?

P.S.: Page is getting redirected to "logout" page on web session expiration.

Answer (score 0):

Vamshi,

If the LTPA token has expired and you try to access a secured resource it will naturally take you to the login page.

That is the expected behaviour!

After you login again you go back to the page you had requested. Depending on your app, either a new HTTPSession is created or it might not even be created during this.

The application should be built to handle this. One approach could be to redirect the user to the main page of the application stating that required information is not available and that you are redirecting the user (after examining the HTTP Session for required information)

HTH